# how you feel feel/ felt

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense, grammaticality-in-context, past-simple

Context: Asking someone if he told his parents about him feeling stressed.

Did you tell him how you ***feel***?

or

Did you tell him how you ***felt***?

Comment: What do you understand the difference in meaning to be between "feel" and "felt"

Comment: If her still feels stressed, both versions are possible. "Did you tell them how you felt (at the time)?" or "how you feel (then and now)" could both  be used .